# Passing parameters from chrome custom tabs to android application

Tags: android, google-chrome, bluetooth, chrome-custom-tabs

I am pretty new to android and would like to know if it is possible to pass parameters from a website in chrome custom tabs to the android application which the runs the custom tabs.

I am creating a web based pos system and running it on chrome custom tabs in android, but the problem is I have a thermal pos printer which only supports bluetooth, so any suggestions or solutions are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a WebView, since that is more customizable and you can control fully.